# how is terminfo delay/padding implemented in TTYs?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, tty, terminfo

I have been looking at terminfo and it has delays, e.g. `$<5>`, in the capability strings. I was trying to see through running `tput` under `strace` how is the delay implemented, i.e., whether it is implemented by, say, `nanosleep` or by inserting `NUL` or other characters. This is the command I have tried to run and trace:

```
TERM=ansi77 strace -o log.txt tput dl1
```

I chose `dl1` on `ansi77` because it is defined as `dl1=\E[M$<5*/>`. However, all I see in the trace is write of 3 bytes:

```
write(1, "\33[M", 3)                    = 3
```

1. So, my question is, how the delay actually implemented? Padding characters or simple process/thread sleep?
2. Can I observe it in terminal emulator or do I need real hardware terminal to see it?
3. Is there any flaw in trying to reproduce it with `tput`?

Comment: The unasked question is the elephant in the room: do modern implementations even bother?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: Well, what if you connect real terminal using serial line? It should respect the delays at least in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreeing with @cliffordheath that padding is done by adding padding characters, reference to the available documentation can help.

Hardware terminals did not cease to exist, they are still [supported by ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#need_padding).  Without padding, these old terminals would not work properly (dropping or mangling your output).  The `vt100` entry uses padding, that for `xterm` does not.

The *terminfo* name for the padding character is **`pad`**; **`pc`** is a termcap name (see [terminfo(5)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Predefined-Capabilities)):

```
   pad_char                  pad    pc   padding char
                                         (instead of null)
```

The terminfo manual page has a lengthy paragraph (in [*Types of Capabilities*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Types-of-Capabilities)) dealing with padding.  There are two types of padding supported in terminfo format (*advisory* and *mandatory*), distinguished by their format.  termcap supports only the latter (using different syntax of course), and unlike terminfo all of the delays happen at one time (making escape sequences for "flash" generally not work).

The command-line [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) program does more than act as a wrapper for the function [`tputs`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html#h3-Output-Functions), but it uses that when outputting strings.  The command-line program provides for outputting boolean, numeric and of course string capabilities.

The library call `tputs` has a parameter for the number of affected lines which is taken into account (like baud rate) in computing delays.

In OP's question

```
dl1=\E[M$<5*/>
```

specifies a delay proportional to the number of lines affected (marked by the `"*"` character).  The number of lines affected for the *command-line* `tput` utility is 1.  It calls [`putp`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html#h3-Output-Functions) to do this. However, that in turn calls [delay_output](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-delay_output), and that calls [baudrate](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_termattrs.3x.html#h3-baudrate).  The last function is initialized only when the terminal is initialized.  The command-line `tput` does *not* initialize the terminal, so delays will not work for *that*.  You should see (given the right speed) delays using the library itself.

ncurses also provides time delays with [`napms`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_kernel.3x.html#h3-napms) (milliseconds), which is different from padding.

Comment: This seems to be a random collection of facts about padding that fails to answer the actual question: if `tput` is supposed to support padding, why don't we see it actually writing any padding bytes in the `strace`?

Comment: If you don't see any nulls, that's because the optimizer determined that none were needed or would affect the result.

Comment: Does `tack` not initialize the terminal? I started investigating this because I was getting `flash` failures in `tack`. The really odd thing is, `tput` seems to sleep, but before writing the whole sequence rather than in the middle of it.

Comment: Also just as a point of curiosity, is "number of lines affected" for something like a line insert/delete/scroll the number of lines deleted, number of lines moved (less if you scroll by more lines), or number of lines changed (distance between cursor and the bottom of the screen, more or less)?

Comment: Think of it as the number of lines to be repainted.

Answer (score 2):

Where delays are implemented, it's done by transmitting pad characters, traditionally NUL characters. The pad character can be changed by a termdata/terminfo setting of the variable *pad* or *pc*.

Pad characters are necessary because the program cannot know when the previously-sent characters have actually been written for it to start a CPU delay. Even if the kernel is done with them after an output flush the characters might still be buffered in the output device UART.

The number of required pad characters is calculated from the baud rate - so it depends on that information being available and accurate.

The tputs routine in the library implements padding (see *man 3 tputs*). I suspect that the command-line tool does too, since it's basically just a wrapper.

Comment: OK. But why can't I see the delay being produced by `tput`?

Comment: I only have very old source code. Unless you're on a terminal connected to a physical RS-232 device, you quite probably won't see any delays.